# How to fix ERROR TypeError: Cannot read undefined properties (reading 'trim') ? Angular 9

Tags: angular

I'm trying to fix a problem in Angular version 9, I get the following error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim').`

Basically what I'm doing is a search engine that when I type it updates the list I have on the screen with the matching results.

The code of the component is the following:

```
searchBan: boolean = false;
  searchKey: string;
  load_data = false;
  no_data = true;

// ...

searchInsideTable() {
    this.listData.filter = this.searchKey.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

And with the `searchInsideTable()` method I have tried to fix it, but without success.

The HTML is the following:

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
 <mat-form-field class="col-md-12 search-form-field">
   <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey" placeholder="Buscar en todos los campos" 
autocomplete="off" class="mat-form-field mat-form-field-fluid" 
(keyup)="searchInsideTable()">
 <mat-hint align="start">
<strong>Buscar en todos los campos</strong>
 </mat-hint>
 </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I'm quite new to Angular yet, any advice or request for information to solve the problem will be very much appreciated from my side.

Comment: Can you please do `F12` and share a console screenshot?

Comment: This is: https://i.imgur.com/4la7NwK.png

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of `undefined` ocouring for `this.searchField` so typescript will advice this, solution is to null check the values! If undefined is set at any stage of the null check it will not proceed to the next stage of the null check.

If `this.searchKey` is `undefined` for example, it will not execute `this.searchKey.trim()` and so on.

```
searchBan: boolean = false;
  searchKey: string;
  load_data = false;
  no_data = true;

// ...

searchInsideTable() {
    const trimmedSearchKey = this.searchKey && this.searchKey.trim();
    this.listData.filter = trimmedSearchKey  && trimmedSearchKey.toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Bro, doing that solves the problem in the console (no longer appears the error message), but still does not work the search engine :c . any idea what it could be?

Comment: @Isanchezo give me a stackblitz withtl the issue replicated and also what you want me to fix please let me know

Comment: Thank you! Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4524wb?file=src/documentos-medida-vehiculo/documentos-medida-vehiculo.component.ts), the folder is 'documents-medida-vehiculo' and the search engine does not work (`<input  matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey"...`)